# Powershell - Looping multiple variables with multiple strings

Tags: loops, powershell, variables, foreach

Not sure if this is even possible but I wanted to ask.

I have a powershell script that does some basic copying of files and directory cleanups.  I need to run the same script in loop but changing two variables each run.

So I would have list of variables:
$tml = @("site1","site2","site3")
$pc = @("pc1","pc2","pc3")

Then my script would be something basic like this:
Copy-Item -Path E:\disaster_rec\$tml\ -Recurse -Destination \$pc\c$\disaster_rec -Force

But through each run, I would want it to use the next variable string in line for each variable.

So it end up running like this:

Copy-Item -Path E:\disaster_rec\site1\ -Recurse -Destination \pc1\c$\disaster_rec -Force

Copy-Item -Path E:\disaster_rec\site2\ -Recurse -Destination \pc2\c$\disaster_rec -Force

Copy-Item -Path E:\disaster_rec\site3\ -Recurse -Destination \pc3\c$\disaster_rec -Force

Is this at all possible and if so, could you point me in the right direction?  I've tried using foreach but can't seem to get it working with two variables.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$tml = @{"site1"="pc1","site2"="pc2","site3"="pc3"}
foreach($key in $tml.Keys)
{
    Copy-Item -Path "E:\disaster_rec\$key\" -Recurse -Destination "\$($tml[$key])\c$\disaster_rec" -Force
}
```

Take a look at hashtables `$tmz = @{"key" = "value"}`

Comment: Updated answer.